# exec ./start.sh: no such file or directory

Tags: django, bash, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Django project that runs in a Docker container within docker-compose.yml with postgresql, pgadmin4 and redis. I have **start.sh** script that make and run migrations:

start.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Creating migrations if they are
python manage.py makemigrations
# Apply migrations
python manage.py migrate
```

After building the image and runing **docker-compose up** command django project give me an error: **exec ./start.sh: no such file or directory** but my start.sh file is in the same directory where Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml are. PostgreSQL, pgadmin4 and Redis runs successfully. How to solve this problem? My system is Windows 10.

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.11.3-alpine

ENV PYTHONBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade

COPY . .

COPY start.sh .

RUN chmod +x start.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "./start.sh" ]

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
services:
  api:
    image: meduzzen-backend-api
    container_name: django
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - ./code:/apps
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres-db
      - redis
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - api-db-redis

  postgres-db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres_db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      api-db-redis:
        # Have access the database using pgadmin4
        ipv4_address: 172.24.0.6

  pg-admin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    container_name: pg_admin
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
    networks:
      - api-db-redis

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis_cache
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - api-db-redis

volumes:
  data:

networks:
  api-db-redis:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.24.0.0/24
```

I've tried to add **\r** in the end of start.sh instructions.Change file destination in Dockerfile.

Comment: The `volumes:` block hides whatever's in the image's `/code` and `/apps` directories and replaces it with content from the host.  This means some Dockerfile steps won't happen (if the `RUN chmod +x` line is important, for example, its result is hidden), and it's possible the filesystem layouts are different.  Does deleting this `volumes:` block help at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you're using an Alpine image and they don't have `bash` installed by default.

In the first line of your script, you've indicated that the script should be run using `bash` and so it fails.

Change the first line in your script to

```
#!/bin/sh
```

and it'll work.

One thing you should be aware of is that Docker only runs a single command when the container starts. When you have both an ENTRYPOINT and a CMD, those are concatenated into a single command. In your case, the command is

```
./start.sh python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I think that you think that they'll be run as two separate commands. They won't.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been suffering from this problem for 2 days.

Comment: Ending the entrypoint script with `exec "$@"` will make it switch over to running the `CMD` (maybe as overridden at run time).  This is standard Bourne shell syntax and will work even with the POSIX shell in the Alpine image.